# How to get Lando to run it's own scripts

Tags: lando

I'm new to Lando, and am surprised at the way it works. I'm following the example at https://docs.lando.dev/wordpress/getting-started.html, and got a WP site up and running.

But I've been reading docs and trying a few things, and can't find a way to avoid having to manually run the lando init function.

I would have thought that having a lando.yml file saying the recipe is wordpress would be enough to get you up and running - my idea being that I could take that same YAML file, modify a few variables like the app URL, and run "lando start" or something to have lando recreate the entire site.

Is there a way to do this?

Andy

Answer (score 1):

You can in fact do exactly this, you don't need to run lando init on a project unless you want to use the included wizard to fill out the `.lando.yml` file. You can simply do the following to run a WordPress site:

```yaml
name: awesome-wp-project
recipe: wordpress
```

place that in the `.lando.yml` in the root of your project and then run `lando start`. You'll have a new instance of Lando with the default configuration for the WordPress recipe running. The important thing to note is that each project needs to have a unique name and should run from a different folder (not nested inside eachother).

You can then include the same customizations in multiple projects (like adding a node container to compile theme assets, or using a specific version of PHP, config file, or folder structure). Just make sure to name each application uniquely.